# How to create WADL programmatically in Jersey

Tags: jersey-2.0, wadl

I am developing a jersey application using Jersey 2.27. I am able to generate a WADL using the out of box feature of Jersey. But I want to control the WADL generation myself via custom code.

Answer (score 0):

WADL generation supported by Jersey 2, but it's [not recommended](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/wadl.html)

> **extended WADL in Jersey 2.x is NOT the intended final version and API is going to be change**

Here's a [tutorial](http://biemond.blogspot.com/2013/08/custom-jersey-wadl-generation.html)

> First I extended the **WadlGeneratorConfig** class in which I defined the following properties **applicationDocsStream, grammarsStream,  resourceDocStream**. These vars point to the xml files which will be used in the WADL generation.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. To be specific, I want to programatically add resources to the WADL. This will solve the puzzle. I went through your tutorial and what I understand is that I will have to have the template XML files for application, grammer and resource. Any insight into this.

Comment: @VishwanathWashimkar you can add properties (not xml) using `prop` method

Comment: Thanks and Sorry to bother you again. Going through WadlGeneratorResourceDocSupport code, I find we can set the following properties - delegate, resourceDocFile, resourceDocStream, resourceDoc . I could run your example and had break points set on WadlGeneratorResourceDocSupport.createResource method. Here is were I want to programtically add resource just for the WADL  purpose. 

Sorry I am not getting how do i set a property to achieve this. It will be great if you can point me to an article. Thanks once again.